# Remove event Listener in scala.js

Tags: javascript, scala, scala.js

I have a list of buttons with an event listener added to them:

```
import org.scalajs.dom.MouseEvent
import org.scalajs.dom.html.Button
import org.scalajs.jquery.{jQuery}
import org.scalajs.dom

def addOnClickToCells(emptyCellButtons: List[Button]) = {
    emptyCellButtons.foreach(emptyCell => {
      emptyCell.addEventListener("click",testButtonOnClick(),false)
    })
  }

def testButtonOnClick() = {
    (e:MouseEvent) => dom.window.alert("Hello")
  }
```

What are want to achieve is just removing the event listener from the list of buttons. Here is what I tried but didn't work:

```
emptyCell.removeEventListener("click",testButtonOnClick(),false)
```

I also tried the below code and expected the event listener to be removed just after it is added, but that doesn't happen (the event listener is not removed).

```
def addOnClickToCells(emptyCellButtons: List[Button]) = {
    emptyCellButtons.foreach(emptyCell => {
      emptyCell.addEventListener("click",testButtonOnClick(),false)
      emptyCell.removeEventListener("click",testButtonOnClick(),false)
    })
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you call `testButtonOnClick()` you get a reference to a new function. Try the following instead:

```
import scala.scalajs.js

val f: js.Function1[MouseEvent, Unit] = testButtonOnClick()
emptyCell.addEventListener("click", f, false)

// Later on
emptyCell.removeEventListener("click", f, false)
```

**Edit:** You might have to explicitly type the functions as a `js.Function1`, otherwise the implicit conversion from `scala.Function1` to `js.Function1` will kick in twice, resulting in references to different functions...